# Set the label colour in tikzcd to be different to the arrow colour

Tags: tikz-cd

The arrows in my tikz-cd graph are green. I would like the label for the arrows to be a different colour. In fact, I would like the text in the label to be of multiple colours. Is it possible to to this?

Comment: That is probably possible. Could you provide a small example document that shows your current output? That would make it much easier to people that want to answer to get started on providing a solution instead of needing to recreate your document first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you want, but here is an example that could be helpful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A\ar[blue]{r}[red]{f}
& B \ar[violet]{r}[swap]{h\circ{\color{cyan}g}} 
& C
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was using syntax like `\arrow[\rightarrow, r, "text" description]` - of course, what you have makes obvious sense. Thank you!

Comment: In that case use `\arrow[rightarrow, blue, r, "{\color{red}text}"{description,inner sep=0.1mm}]` note that `description` adds a white rectangle to the label, so you may want it a little smaller.